# Не сохраняется положение Switch, Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, switch

Я недавно начал изучения данного фреймворка, поэтому если что-то говорю неправильно, поправьте пожалуйста. А теперь к вопросу: почему виджет Switch (я использую CupertinoSwitch) не может переключиться из положения off в on? Этот вопрос уже гуглил, но те ответы, которые были, не помогли.
Вот мой код:

```
CupertinoSwitch(
     value: flag1,
     onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
             flag1 = value;
           });
      },
 )
```

Пример работы выше указанного кода можно посмотреть [тут](https://vk.com/video618736437_456239017). То есть, при простом нажатии ничего не происходит, а если удержать саму метку (белый кружок), то перевести м положение on можно, но когда отпускаешь метку, switch переходит в положение off

**UPD**

Полный код:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cupertino_settings/flutter_cupertino_settings.dart';

void main() => runApp(SettingsScreen());

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: SettingScreen(),
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(primaryColor: CupertinoColors.activeBlue),
    );
  }
}

class SettingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SettingScreenState();
}

class SettingScreenState extends State<SettingScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool flag1 = false;
    bool flag2 = true;
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('Настройки'),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: CupertinoSettings(items: <Widget>[
            const CSHeader('Интерфейс'),
            CSControl(
                nameWidget: Text('Полупрозрачные кнопки'),
                contentWidget: CupertinoSwitch(
                  value: flag1,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      flag1 = value;
                      print(flag1);
                    });
                  },
                )),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Использую эту библиотеку для настроек - [flutter_cupertino_settings](https://github.com/matthinc/flutter_cupertino_settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код правильный, но по описанию, кажется что у вас где-то в build методе есть переопределение переменной **flag1**, если это так, то определение стартовых значений переменных в state необходимо делать методе **initState**
[офф дока по методу initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)

Прикрепите полный код вашего виджета и тогда можно будет указать точную причину.

UPDATE

Вместо того чтобы задавать изначальные значение в **build** методе как это делается здесь:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool flag1 = false;
    bool flag2 = true;
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
```

Нужно вынести эти переменные в state и переопределить метод initState вот так:

```
bool flag1;
bool flag2;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  flag1 = false;
  flag2 = true;
}
```

дальше в build методе обращаться к ним и перерисовывать как хочется

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('Настройки'),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: CupertinoSettings(items: <Widget>[
            const CSHeader('Интерфейс'),
            CSControl(
                nameWidget: Text('Полупрозрачные кнопки'),
                contentWidget: CupertinoSwitch(
                  value: flag1,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      flag1 = value;
                      print(flag1);
                    });
                  },
                )),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Наверное, код прикрепил, посмотрите пожалуйста, буду признателен. И ещё, можете подсказать, как сохранять настройки в другом классе? Просто в Android это можно сделать через метод onResume(). Заранее спасибо

Comment: @DmIvanov1970 сохранять настройки чего именно? Не очень понятно

Comment: @DmIvanov1970 дополнил ответ, смотрите, должно заработать. Почитайте про методы жизненого цикла виджетов во flutter.
Если вы пришли из мира андроида (как я понял), то вот статья должна подойти

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-lifecycle-for-android-and-ios-developers-8f532307e0c7

Comment: @DmIvanov1970 помогло?

Comment: сохранять настройки WebView. Допустим отключение JS через класс настроек. Спасибо, что дополнили ответ. проверю чуть позже, но по моему должно работать. Спасибо ещё раз :)

Comment: @DmIvanov1970 думаю это тема для отдельного вопроса, удачи!

Comment: да, всё верно. Спасибо Вам за разъяснение моей глупой ошибки :)

Answer (score 0):

Все работает

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool flag1 = false;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoSwitch(
      value: flag1,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          flag1 = value;
          print(flag1);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```